# PhpMailer accented characters not recognized in external IE application

Tags: php, character-encoding, phpmailer, charset

Good morning,
I have a problem with my php page that sends mails using PhpMailer because everything I enter with accented letters when it is sent to the external application, which uses Internet Explorer since it is old, is downloaded with unaccented characters; I guess it is a coding problem and for this I tried to do some tests that I put here below:

```
$today = date("F j, Y, g:i a"); 
require'PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer(true);
$mail->IsSMTP(); // telling the class to use SMTP
$mail->SMTPDebug  = 0;
$mail->SMTPAuth = true; 


$mail->Host = "####";    
$mail->Username = "####";
$mail->Password = "####";
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
$mail->Port = ####;
$mail->From = "####";

$mail->FromName = '';
$mail->charSet = "multipart/alternative";
$mail->AddAddress("####");
$mail->Subject = utf8_decode($oggetto);
$mail->Body = utf8_decode($messaggio);
```

below is the message to be sent to an external application that needs special tags:

```
    $messaggio = '<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=ISO-8859-15">'
. '<!--MF@[WEB]--><strong>ORDINE</strong>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;num. <!--MF$[NUM]-->' . $numero_ordine . '<!--MF&[NUM]-->&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;del <!--MF$[DAT]-->' . $data . '<!--MF&[DAT]--><br/>'
. '<hr/><br/>'
. 'Azienda: <!--MF$[SOC]-->' . $UserSoc . '<!--MF&[SOC]--> ' . $strSocCts . '<br />'
. $strSdi
. $strInd . '<br/>'
. $strPiv . '<br/>'
. $strCRS . '<br/>'
. $strTel . '<br />'
. $strEma . '<br />'
. '<br />'
. 'Dati recapito:<br />'
. '<hr/>'
. $strRecSoc . '<br/>'
. $strRecInd . $strRecTel . $strRecEma
. '<br /><br />'
. $prodott
. '<hr/>'
. 'Subtotale materiale: ' . fix($total) . ' euro  + Trasporto: ' . $trasporto . ' euro <br />'
. $ivatotale . $sconto . $pagamento 
. 'Vettore: ' . $vettore . '<br />'
. '<hr>'
. $totaletotale
. $annotazioni
. 'Note :&nbsp; <br/><hr>'
. $UserNec . '<br/><br/>';
```

As tests for encoding I tested these but I only got characters with no accent or "weird" characters.

```
/**
     * The character set of the message.
     * @type string
     */
    public $CharSet = 'UTF-8';


    /**
     * The MIME Content-type of the message.
     * @type string
     */
    public $ContentType = 'text/plain';
```

trying to put as charset = ISO-8859-1 or UTF8 but without results.

I just don't understand where I'm wrong.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try changing the HTML meta (`<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=ISO-8859-15">`) to UTF-8

Comment: done, but nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly you're using a very old and unsupported version of PHPMailer, so [upgrade](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer).

Next:

```
$mail->charSet = "multipart/alternative";
```

PHP is case sensitive for property names, so this will fail to set the `CharSet` property. Even if it did work, `multipart/alternative` is a MIME type, not a character set name.

The `utf8_decode` function converts UTF-8 text into ISO-8859-1, for the set of characters that are common to both character sets. Whether that is appropriate depends on your input string actually being in UTF=8, and the output being expected to be ISO-8859-1; if either of these are incorrect, it will make a mess.

Generally speaking, you want to use UTF-8 everywhere, and if you do that, all you should need to do is:

```
$mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
```

and if your content is already in UTF-8 (which it probably is), you can then simply do:

```
$mail->Subject = $oggetto;
$mail->Body = $messaggio;
```

Comment: `$mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';`

Comment: `'$mail->CharSet = 'multipart/alternative;'`
i forgot to edit it before posting it, I was already using utf-8 there too.
Could the old version really be the problem or is there something else?

Comment: The old version won't have anything to do with this issue, but the version you're using is now very old and may have known vulnerabilities. If you're setting `CharSet = 'UTF-8'` but still using `utf8_decode`, that will break as I described.

Comment: I found the solution, thanks also to @Synchro!
`$mail->FromName = '';
   // $mail->charSet = "ISO-8859-1";
    $mail->charSet = "UTF-8";
    $mail->Encoding = 'base64';
    $mail->AddAddress("ordini@neca.it"); //luzzi.roberto@gmail.com
    $mail->IsHTML(true);
    $mail->Subject = utf8_decode($oggetto);
    $mail->Body = utf8_decode($messaggio);``